# Subplot two graph plotting in two differents functions matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, subplot

I can't find anywhere how to subplot two graph next to each other with differents functions plotting them. Can anyone help me please? I work with Jupyter Notebook.

First function:

```
def OccurrenciesPlotting(filtered_sent):
    fdist = FreqDist(filtered_sent)      
    fdist.plot(40,cumulative=False)
```

Seconde function:

```
def MyWordCloud(filtered_sent):
    img  = np.array(Image.open("H....jpg")) 
    stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)
    .
    .
    .

    image_colors = ImageColorGenerator(img)

    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(wordcloud.recolor(color_func=image_colors),
               interpolation="bilinear")
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.savefig('wordcloud.png', format="png")
    plt.show()
```

And I want the result of the function one next to the other

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For plotting subplots you have to use the plt.subplots() function. Your figure is then the graph including both subplots and each subplot sits on one axis-object. 
As your code is not reproducible, as we lack the data, I cannot provide you with the full code. 
In general, you should pass the axis that you want your function to plot on to be passed as an argument.
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3], "b": [2,3,4]})

def f1(df, axis):
    return df["a"].plot(ax = axis)

def f2(df, axis):
    axis = plt.plot(df["b"], c = "g")
    return axis

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows =1, ncols = 2)
f1(df, axes[0])
axes[1] = f2(df, axes[1])
plt.show()
```

As you can see, you have to use a slightly different method when using the pandas plotting function and matplotlibs functions. You can pass the desired axis to the df.plot() with the ax argument. For using the regular matplotlib libraries I returned an axis object from the function.